# circular movement of 3 bodies

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, kinematics, celestial-mechanics

Im trying to find the $(x,y)$ coordinate of 3 bodies which move in circle -
for example (sun > earth > moon).
Assume sun is always at (0,0).
Earth orbit around the sun.
Moon orbit around earth. (no masses etc.)
Assume we have:
`initial angle`, `speed`, `radius`.
earth has `distance from sun`, moon has `distance from earth`.
How can I calculate the current position of the moon using these variables?

Comment: In my opinion you also need the initial position of the Earth and the moon, and the velocity of them - these are not stated on your question. What are these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{r}_{earth} &= (R\cos \Omega t,R\sin \Omega t) \\
  \mathbf{r}_{moon} &=
  (R\cos \Omega t+r\cos (\omega t+\phi),R\sin \Omega+r\sin (\omega t+\phi)) \\
\end{align*}